# TS2540: Cannot assign to 'href' because it is a read-only property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

For some reason in my react app, the following code triggers a compilation error in Webpack using the typescript loader (`ts-loader`):

```
handleEdit(): void {
    window.location.href = `/edit/${this.props.entry.id}`;
}
```

> TS2540: Cannot assign to 'href' because it is a read-only property.

I suspect it's some kind of odd artifact of my environment. I have this environment:

> "react": "^17.0.1"
> webpack: 5.61.0
> webpack-cli: 4.9.1
> webpack-dev-server 4.11.1
> "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
> "typescript": "^4.4.4",

Comment: Is `window` the global window or do you have a variable in scope with a different type? Is any of your other packages messing with the type? You could work around it by casting to `any`: `(window.location as any).href = ...`

Comment: window is the global window

Comment: could you try **window.location.assign(url)** instead of **href** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `window.location.assign`. [from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-location-assign-in-javascript/)

> window.location.assign Property:
>
> - The assign function is similar to the href property as it is also used to navigate to a new URL.
> - The assign method, however, does not show the current location, it is only used to go to a new location.
> - Unlike the replace method, the assign method adds a new record to history (so that when the user clicks the “Back” button, he/she can
>   return to the current page).
> - However, rather than updating the href property, calling a function is considered safer and more readable.
> - The assign() method is also preferred over href as it allows the user to mock the function and check the URL input parameters while
>   testing.

```
window.location.assign(`/edit/${this.props.entry.id}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out the answer. My workaround was using `react-dom-router` and changing all instances of `window.location.href = ...` to `reload(...)`, which solved the problem.